# hstack out of memory

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I've got a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` object who's size is `full_sites_sparse.shape` `(336358, 48371)`. Also I have dataframe who's size is `union_df[hour].shape` `(336358, 17)`. I want to union there and get another one with size `(336358, 48388)` I try union there with:

```
full_sites_hour_sparse = np.hstack((full_sites_sparse.A, union_df[hour].values))
```

and

```
full_sites_hour_sparse = scipy.sparse.hstack(full_sites_sparse.A, union_df[hour].values)
```

But both raise out of memory exception. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Tell us about `unuon_df[hour]`.  dtype?  what happens with `sparse.coo_matrix(union_df[hour])`?

Comment: Does this `union_df` have a lot of 0 values? Is it sparse?

Comment: @hpaulj All values in both are binary(0,1). `unuon_df[hour]. dtype` is `int8`. After `sparse.coo_matrix(union_df[hour])` is `<336358x17 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.uint8'>`

Comment: The `sparse.hstack` makes a new sparse matrix from the two inputs.  There's no way around that.  It might help if you showed the full traceback, at least to pinpoint where in the new matrix construction the error occurs,

Comment: @hpaulj I try this `full_sites_hour_sparse = np.hstack((full_sites_sparse.A[:10000], union_df[hour].values[:10000]))` and it's work. I think the problem is with not enough memory.