# Join two numpy arrays with the same rows: I got a ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

The dataset I'm using has some columns that are categories. I applied OneHotEncoder to them. Then, I tried to join the array the numeric features and the array that is result of OneHotEncoder, thus forming a single array with all the features!

The first array is `(5074382, 82)` and the second is `(5074382, 9276434)`

I tried:

```
features_final = np.column_stack((features2, features_encoded))
```

`features_final` will be used instead of `features`

features_encoded

```
(5074382, 9276434)    dtype('float64')   scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

features2

```
(5074382, 82)       dtype('float64')       numpy.ndarray
```

The code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    pd.options.display.max_columns = None  #Display all dataframe columns in a Jupyter Python Notebook
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

    CIC2019 = pd.read_csv(r"DrDoS_DNS.csv")

    remove =lambda x:x.strip()# remove the blancks in columns names

    columns = list(CIC2019.columns)

    new_columns =list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),columns))# removing blamcks

    CIC2019 = pd.read_csv(r"CSV-01-12\DrDoS_DNS.csv", names =new_columns, header = None, skiprows=1,nrows=None)
    CIC2019.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 0": "ID"}, inplace=True)

    CIC2019 = CIC2019.dropna()
    CIC2019.isna().sum()

    features = CIC2019.drop("Label", axis =1)

    # # Handling categorical attributes

    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    encoder = OneHotEncoder()

    CIC2019["Label"]

    Label_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(CIC2019["Label"].to_numpy().reshape(1,-1))

    features[["Flow ID","Source IP","Timestamp","SimillarHTTP","Destination IP"]]

    features2 = features.drop(["Flow ID","Source IP","Timestamp","Destination IP","SimillarHTTP"], axis =1)
    features2 = features2.to_numpy()

    features_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(features[["Flow ID","Source IP","Timestamp","Destination IP",]].to_numpy())
    #"SimillarHTTP" : error when you added this
    # # Training - Linear Regression

    features_final = np.column_stack((features2, features_encoded))
```

I got the error:

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 5074382 and the array at index 1 has size 1

What happened? How to fix it?

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example.  For example, if I do `a=np.arange(8).reshape(4,2); b=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3); np.column_stack((a,b))` there is no error.

Comment: It would seem your `features_encoded` has a shape of `(1, x)` instead.

Comment: @r.ook  features_encoded.shape ->(5074382, 9276434)

Comment: Then you need to see how to create a [mre] because the error message clearly says the second array has a shape of `(1, x)`.  It cannot be reproduced with your information given.

Comment: @r.ook I put a link for the complete code

Comment: @stevemo     I put a link for the complete code

Comment: The code should be directly in the body of the question itself.  One very good reason is that your site is blocked from my end and I can't view anything.  Also, the code should be *minimum* necessary to produce the issue, not the *complete* code.

Comment: @r.ook : I put the code

Comment: Again - the code should be *minimum*.  We're not here to troubleshoot your entire code, but to provide help on a particular issue.  e.g., we still don't have any idea what your input is, and I don't even see `np.column_stack` being used.  You are not even using `features_encoded`, but `Label_encoded`.

Comment: @r.ook I did not use features_encoded because of the error!

Comment: @r.ook  features_final will be used instead of features

Comment: @r.ook The only error is in  features_final = np.column_stack((features2, features_encoded))

Comment: Honestly I would love to help but you are not making this any easier... I stress that you read how to create a [mre] of your problem.  A sample input would be a *great* start, because right now I'm flying blind.  `features_encoded` cannot have a shape of `(5074382, 9276434)` if you are executing the `np.column_stack` right after the name assignment.  It is either a shape of `(1, x [, ...])` or the shape is as you said, and you will *not* get that error.  There's conflicting info here and you need to clarify these details.

Comment: @r.ook The error changed! ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 5074382 and the array at index 1 has size 1

Comment: Immediately before the `column_stack` call you need to `print` the `shape` (and `dtype`) of `features2`, `features_encoded`.  Since we can't recreate your calculations, you have to provide all of the debugging data.  Don't assume anything!  test!

Comment: That's the same error as before.  I think until you update your question to be a [mre] with sample inputs I have exhausted all avenue to be of help.

Comment: @hpaulj   I will edit the post!

Comment: To give you an example of MRE, and why your issue is not reproducible: https://ideone.com/ySOSgb as you can see the error message is the same.  Perhaps the `numpy` version on server is different but if you run it you'll get the exact same error message, which hows your `feature_encoded.shape` is not what you think it is when you run `np.column_stack`

Comment: @hpaulj    features_encoded -> (5074382, 9276434)                    dtype('float64')    features2 -> (5074382, 82)       dtype('float64')

Comment: About that `features_encoded`, what's its `type`?  `ndarray` or something else.  That might be too big to be a dense `ndarray` (requiring 42 Tb of memory).

Comment: @hpaulj  features_encoded -> (5074382, 9276434)    dtype('float64')      scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix  /  features2 -> (5074382, 82)       dtype('float64')    numpy.ndarray

Comment: `np.column_stack` (and any of the `np.concatenate` or `stack` functions) cannot be used with `sparse` matrices.  There is a `sparse.hstack` that might work for you.  But see this related SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393406/hstack-out-of-memory

Comment: @hpaulj tks. Is there a better way to encode categorical variables without sparse matrices?